# PHP Xpath How to retrieve the innertext of strong with id

Tags: php, xpath

I have this code, and I want to get the text inside the "strong" code.
The html output that from there I want the value:

```
<strong id="sku-price">199.98</strong>
```

And this the code that I use now

```
$link = "http://www.example.com";
$html = file_get_contents($link);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$check = $xpath->query('//strong[@id="sku-price"]');
foreach($check as $p){
  **Then I don't know what to write here to get the value** 
}
```

Currently it's not work, please need help to get it sorted.

Thank you.

Comment: What isn't working? `$check` will be a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/class.domnodelist.php) which you need to iterate

Comment: add more information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

`$check` would be a [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php).
Since you are using an id, you could get the first item from that list which would be a [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) and get the nodeValue:

```
echo $check->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

If you want to use a foreach you could update your code to:

```
foreach($check as $p){
    echo $p->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: @Haviv This is a [demo](https://3v4l.org/2fDAT) using the html from your example. Are you sure that the html contains your `<strong id="sku-price">`? Can you check what `var_dump($check->length);` gives you? Or check if there are any `<strong>` elements at all? Like `var_dump($html);` or  `var_dump($xpath->query('//strong'));`

Comment: Gonna go out on a limb here and suspect the remote page loads data via JavaScript

Comment: @The fourth bird `var_dump($check->length)` gives me `int(0)`,and `var_dump($xpath->query('//strong'))` gives me `object(DOMNodeList)#4 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(0)
}`

Comment: If that is returned, I think @Phil might be right that the data loads via JavaScript.

Comment: An through javascript I can't get the values? In the F12 I can see values, but when I do view-source you right, I don't see any value

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possibilities. You can read the `$textContent` property. It contains the text content of all descendant nodes.

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//strong[@id="sku-price"]');
foreach($nodes as $strong) {
  var_dump($strong->textContent); 
}
```

Or you fetch it directly with Xpath. `DOMXpath::evaluate()` supports Xpath expressions that return scalar values. Cast the node list in the expression into a string.

```
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(//strong[@id="sku-price"])');
```